# Как можно переполнить стек?

Tags: память, стек

Какими самыми примитивными способами возможно переполнить стек?

Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры ко своему ответу.

Comment: Запустить бесконечную рекурсию.

Comment: Почитайте поподробнее про fork()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного неожиданно, но этот код не будет переполнять стек на платформах, в которых компилятор (или JIT) умеет делать [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).Например, на C# / x64 он просто выполняется бесконечно.

Comment: Хорошее замечание, спасибо!